# adding two value in a class in python

Tags: python

I am knew at this and not sure the exact syntax to use to add x,y in python using this class definition

```
class Add(values):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        values.__init__(self, [x, y])

    def forward(self):

        return self.values[x] + values[1]
```

I am not able to figure out how to access x,y to add them together. I have tried all the possibilities that I can think of. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Add`?

Comment: What is `values`?

Comment: Executing that code gives the error `NameError: name 'values' is not defined`.

Comment: Prove an example of how you would actually *use* `Add`, and what the result of using it should be.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want a function and not a class.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

If you're sure that this really has to be a class for whatever you're doing, it can look like this:

```
class Add:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def forward(self):
        return self.x+self.y
```

Then

```
>>>add(5, 6)
11
>>>a = Add(5, 6)
>>>a.forward()
11
```

Comment: I have to keep the code in that format as it is part of a larger code and it is one of the class definitions. The values itself is an instance of another class so I have to return the sum to it. so if I just say sef.x=x self.y=y  and return x+y  I will get NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Comment: @kevbuntu Could you share the code for `values` then?  The way we set up `Add` really depends on how `values` is set up

Answer (score 3):

i think that is what you need

```
class Values():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y=0):
        self.x_value = x
        self.y_value = y

class Add(Values):
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y=0):
        Values.__init__(self, x, y)

    def forward(self):
        return (self.x_value + self.y_value)

add = Add(x = 20, y=20)
print (add.forward())
```

Comment: This is part of a bigger code where" values" itself is an instance of a class. I need to keep the code in  the format I stated

Comment: Unless `values` is an instance of `type` (or a subclass thereof), it doesn't belong in the base-class list of a `class` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

To add something to other answers, I would say that :

```
class Add(values):
```

means that you create class 'Add' who inherits from the class 'values'. Class 'values' must be defined somewhere otherwise you will have the NameError.

More info about inheritance here :
https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: I can not change the code to something else. I basically need to have values=x+y within the forward function. No other variety of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer I was looking for is :

self.x =[0]
self.y = [1]

Thanks for the tries.